# Prove that the sequence is convergent (and bounded): $b_{n} = \sqrt{n^{2}+1} - \sqrt{n^{2}+2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Prove that the sequence is convergent and bounded: $b_{n} =
> \sqrt{n^{2}+1} - \sqrt{n^{2}+2n}$

I got troubles proofing it's convergent, here is what I did and I believe I'm on the right track:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{n^{2}+2n}= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{n^{2}+2n})\cdot (\sqrt{n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{n^{2}+2n})}{(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{n^{2}+2n})}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{2}+1-(n^{2}+2n)}{\sqrt{n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{n^{2}+2n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-2n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{n^{2}+2n}}$$

Here is the point where I don't know / not sure how to continue. I would probably go on by excluding $n^{2}$ in both numerator and denominator. But the square-roots are interfering me to do it, somehow.

Any ideas how this could be done? If my way is correct, I'd like to see the full and correct version of it. Please don't post a complete different way! :-)

Abound the bounded thing, I think that's really no problem to solve after knowing the limit, so I will just skip it here.

Comment: At the last step, divide the numerator and denominator by $n$, and use $n=\sqrt{n^2}$.  Then you should be all set

Comment: Damn, so easy and I didn't see it, thank you very much @Simple Art  :)

Answer (score 5):

Write $$\sqrt{n^2+1}=\sqrt{n^2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)}=n\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}$$
and
$$\sqrt{n^2+2n}=n\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2}{n}}$$
to exclude $n$ from both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, show $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}=0$ and conclude
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2+2n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt{n^2}-\sqrt{n^2+2n+1})  $$

Comment: How did you do the second part?