# Prove that the series is bounded $b_{n} = \frac{1-2n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+1} + \sqrt{n^{2}+2n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

*It was part of the task of my previous question, I didn't want put both in one: [Prove that the sequence is convergent (and bounded): $b_{n} = \sqrt{n^{2}+1} - \sqrt{n^{2}+2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931446/prove-that-the-sequence-is-convergent-and-bounded-b-n-sqrtn21) .*

> So given is the sequence: $b_{n} = \frac{1-2n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+1} + \sqrt{n^{2}+2n}}$.
>   We know that its limit is $-1$. Now I'm supposed to prove that it's
>   bounded series.

To show it's bounded, we take the limit $-1$ and equalize it with $b_{n}$ and calculate $n$. Then check if $n$ is lower(-equal) or greater(-equal) $-1$:

$$\frac{1-2n}{\sqrt{n^{2}+1} + \sqrt{n^{2}+2n}} = -1$$

$$\frac{(1-2n)^{2}}{(n^{2}+1)+(n^{2}+2n)} = 1$$

$$\frac{(1-2n)^{2}}{2n^{2}+2n+1} = 1$$

$$(1-2n)^{2} = 2n^{2}+2n+1$$

$$4n^{2}-4n+1 = 2n^{2}+2n+1$$

$$0 = 2n^{2}-6n$$

$$0 = n(2n-6)$$

$n_{1} = -3 < -1 \Rightarrow$ upper bound

$n_{2} = 0 > -1 \Rightarrow$ lower bound

And this the series is bounded.

---

Is that correct?

Comment: Unless specifically asked, I would not do all the computation. I would simply state that any convergent sequence is bounded (do you know how to prove this?) and consequently $b_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Alright lol, I have just checked results and it's exactly described as you said.. ^.^

Comment: But anyway I'd like to know if I did it correctly please :)

Comment: $n$ is here a natural number

Comment: Ohh so I can ignore $n_{1}$ because it's negative and so the series has only lower bound, right?

Comment: I don't really understand what you've done, to be honest. I'll try to write a proof for boundedness (does this word exist?)

Comment: What I did is find limit for $n\rightarrow \infty$ (given in task) it's $-1$. This is infimum $i$. Now we need prove: $b_{n} \geq i$. I did that above, tried, whatever :p

Answer (score 1):

we have $$a_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2+2n}$$ it is $$a_n<0$$ since $$n^2+1<n^2+2n$$ which is true. Further we get
$$-1<\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2+2n}$$ and this is true since
$$\sqrt{n^2+2n}<\sqrt{n^2+1}+1$$ is equivalent
$$2n-2<2\sqrt{n^2+1}$$
$$n-1<\sqrt{n^2+1}$$
squaring gives
$$n^2-2n+1<n^2+1$$ this is true since $$n\geq 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is between -2n and 0.

The denominator is greater than 2n.

So their ratio is between -1 and 0

Comment: This is a good solution